# Make backup DC as primary and remove the old primary one

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

Hope you are doing well. I have a machine which is running Windows Server 2016. It is acting as DC, DNS and DHCP. This machine is old and I was using it temporary. Now, I have got my new servers and installed on one Windows Server 2016. I had installed DC, DNS and DHCP on it, and made it as a DC in the same domain for the first machine. So, I am having now:
1- AD1 : ad1.mydomain.com (Old machine)
2- AD  : ad.mydomain.com  (New machine)

The repadmin log as following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator.mydomain>repadmin /showrepl

Repadmin: running command /showrepl against full DC localhost
Default-First-Site-Name\AD
DSA Options: IS_GC
Site Options: (none)
DSA object GUID: 4cddd0c2-bb81-4189-9d8e-bb55450a4f21
DSA invocationID: df7d8272-6c76-408a-9a54-f67577171c62

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=mydomain,DC=com
    Default-First-Site-Name\AD1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6726bb5b-9aac-4525-85fe-17d3f767e266
        Last attempt @ 2017-05-30 08:20:08 was successful.

CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    Default-First-Site-Name\AD1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6726bb5b-9aac-4525-85fe-17d3f767e266
        Last attempt @ 2017-05-30 07:53:37 was successful.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    Default-First-Site-Name\AD1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6726bb5b-9aac-4525-85fe-17d3f767e266
        Last attempt @ 2017-05-30 07:53:37 was successful.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    Default-First-Site-Name\AD1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6726bb5b-9aac-4525-85fe-17d3f767e266
        Last attempt @ 2017-05-30 07:53:37 was successful.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    Default-First-Site-Name\AD1 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6726bb5b-9aac-4525-85fe-17d3f767e266
        Last attempt @ 2017-05-30 07:53:37 was successful.
```

I had also backed up my DHCP database from AD1 using:

```
netsh server dhcp export C:\dhcp-db.txt all
```

And imported back into my new DC.

My question is, how do I make AD (the new DC) as primary DC and remove the old one totally?! Is is enough to demote AD1 so AD will be the primary?!

Regards,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's enough to demote the old machine. There is no "primary" DC, this is an old concept. All DCs are equal. One DC holds FSMO roles, these get transfered automatically if you demote the machine holding these roles. Be aware that it is not a best practice to only use one DC in a production environment, make sure you have at least two DCs for redundancy.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I will install another DC but it will be on new machine. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

First You have install new DC with ad2.mydomain.com. Once the new Machine is act as ADC (For Backup Redundancy). Then you seize the roles of DC in your ad1.mydomain.com. Make sure all the FIVE FSMO roles are moved to ad.mydomain.com.

Before that Go to your any of the DC. Run **netdom query fsmo**.
The Output will show Five roles are assign to which DC?

If you Find any role is assigned to ad1.mydomain.com. You have move it.
Go to Power shell run as administrator run this command **Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity ad.mydomain.com -OperationMasterRole SchemaMaster, DomainNamingMaster, PDCEmulator, RIDMaster, InfrastructureMaster**

***In command you can see i have added Five roles name also. Make sure only add role to moved from ad1.mydomain to ad.mydomain.com.***

Once its completed, type netdom query fsmo again Cross verify is it moved properly.

Later You have clear metadata of ad1.mydomain.com or Uninstall AD. (To Remove Completely)
Logon to ad1.mydomain.com (Old DC) Go to Powershell
Run this command **Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -DemoteOperationMasterRole -RemoveApplicationPartition** and press enter.

It will ask for local administrator password. provide new password for local administrator and press enter.

Later once again your can cross check is any metadata is remaining in ad.mydomain.com. Like in DNS, Sites and services etc. If you found any entry old ad1.mydomain.com you can delete it of.

Comment: I'm not sure you intended it this way, but your phrasing makes it very unclear what order these steps actually need to occur in. Could you clarify the steps and the words you use to note them? Perhaps use the numbered list function just to make it super clear?